# Can all LLVM frontends produce the same bytecode

Tags: llvm, bytecode, llvm-ir

LLVM is the backend for many languages such as C#, Ruby, Zig and so on.

My question is: can all LLVM frontend languages “in principle” produce the same LLVM bytecode?

Are there any minimum requirements for a frontend to be able to produce the same byte code as say, C++?

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes… except not quite. Because the C++ language requires that the bytecode access c++ vtbls and other constructs  that aren't *quite* the same in other languages.

One language may require that a null pointer check be inserted in a particular spot, another language makes it possible to elide that check. The output from two languages will always have tiny differences like that.